# After Installing openam j2eeagent, tomcat is throwing NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: tomcat, openam

We have deployed openam on Tomcat 7 on one system and j2eeagent on another in same network.

But After installation, the tomcat server having j2eeagent deployement is throwing below mentioned errors on startup- 
We have tried the same with Tomcat 6 with same result
**We have followed the below link for our installation:
http://docs.forgerock.org/en/openam-pa/3.3.0/jee-install-guide/index/chap-apache-tomcat.html#install-agent-into-tomcat7

Any help will be appreciated

---

```
SEVERE: Begin event threw error
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/identity/authentication/callbacks/HiddenValueCallback
    at com.sun.identity.authentication.share.AuthXMLUtils.getXMLForCallbacks(AuthXMLUtils.java:392)
    at com.sun.identity.authentication.AuthContext.submitRequirements(AuthContext.java:1289)
    at com.sun.identity.authentication.AuthContext.submitRequirements(AuthContext.java:1252)
    at com.sun.identity.agents.common.ApplicationSSOTokenProvider.getApplicationSSOToken(ApplicationSSOTokenProvider.java:71)
    at com.sun.identity.agents.arch.AgentConfiguration.setAppSSOToken(AgentConfiguration.java:616)
    at com.sun.identity.agents.arch.AgentConfiguration.bootStrapClientConfiguration(AgentConfiguration.java:722)
    at com.sun.identity.agents.arch.AgentConfiguration.initializeConfiguration(AgentConfiguration.java:1140)
    at com.sun.identity.agents.arch.AgentConfiguration.<clinit>(AgentConfiguration.java:1579)
    at com.sun.identity.agents.arch.Manager.<clinit>(Manager.java:675)
    at com.sun.identity.agents.tomcat.v6.AmTomcatRealm.<clinit>(AmTomcatRealm.java:67)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:374)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.ObjectCreateRule.begin(ObjectCreateRule.java:145)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.startElement(Digester.java:1288)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(AbstractSAXParser.java:509)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractXMLDocumentParser.emptyElement(AbstractXMLDocumentParser.java:182)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:1342)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2770)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:606)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:510)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:848)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:777)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1213)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:648)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.parse(Digester.java:1561)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:615)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:663)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:280)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:454)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.identity.authentication.callbacks.HiddenValueCallback
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    ... 37 more
```

Comment: You are using a nightly agent with a buggy SDK:
https://bugster.forgerock.org/jira/browse/OPENAM-4324

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, due to lack of documentation.

You need to copy the ClientSDK-11.0.0.jar provided by the
[OpenAm zip](https://backstage.forgerock.com/downloads/enterprise/openam/openam11/11.0.0/OpenAM-11.0.0.zip)
in the lib folder of your Tomcat hosting the web application you want to protect.

Comment: This is a follow up issue to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25430057/after-installing-openam-j2eeagent-tomcat-is-throwing-noclassdeffounderror?rq=1.

Including the ClientSDK-11.0.0.jar solved that issue. But we gotthis error later on.
_________________________________________________
we have downloaded:
tomcat_v6_agent_4.0.0-SNAPSHOT
from following link
http://forgerock.org/downloads/openam-builds/
and we are getting error as mentioned in below link: 
http://bugster.forgerock.org/jira/browse/OPENAM-3480